# How to test uploading a complete folder with protractor?

Tags: angular, file-upload, protractor, angular-material, e2e-testing

I'm trying to test a form which includes the upload of a folder, where the site extracts information from the files inside that folder. If I try the usual `path.resolve()` and `sendKeys()` the test doesn't output any errors until it tries to submit the form, which requires those files. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this or some kind of workaround, for example by changing the html. Most changes should be fine as long as the current functionalities remain unchanged.

The following html is the snippet that accepts the folder.

```html
<input
 #upload
 id="someID"
 type="file"
 webkitdirectory
 directory
 (change)="extractDataOutOfUploadedFolder($event.target.files)"
 class="display-none"
 required
/>
```

I want to upload the folder in a way, that the backend can process it as if a user used the upload popup

Comment: what kind of error do you get?

Comment: I don't get an error for the upload. My check if the button to send the form is active just times out